# Swyftx Airdrops, Rewards ,stacking

Tags: cryptojs, binance, cryptocurrency

I am creating a tax calculator. I am trying to get the airdrops and rewards for the swyftx exchange but cannot seem to find the appropriate route. I have tried the stacking history route but it doesn't return the complete records for the rewards. Any help would be appreciated.